# Mapping a List to concurrent.futures ends the task early? - Python

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrent.futures

**Main goal**: I would like to crawl *N* paths on one website. I also would like to do this on *T* number of threads.

An example that I can run successfully is doing 10 paths with 10 threads or 10 threads with 5 threads each time. The problem with the latter is that it opens 5 chrome browsers, then opens another 5 chrome browsers.

What I would ideally like is to have 5 chrome browsers (*T* threads) that each has a list of ids to go through.

In the code I have linked below it successfully goes through index[0] of each list. However once it gets to the next item it stops running.

For example, it will run path ids 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. But it will stop on path/id=6, 7, 8, 9, 10.

Function:

```
import concurrent.futures

def pathCrawler(idList):
    DRIVER_PATH = 'chromedriver'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
    path = 'fake.../id='
    

    for id in idList:
        print('start')
        driver.get(path + str(id))
        # Try Hitting #1 Button
        try:
            # XPath for #1 Button
            driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '').click() 
            print(f'{id}: success 1')

            #Try Hitting #2 Button 
            try:
                # XPath for #2 Button
                driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '').click()  
                print(f'{id}: success 2')
            except:
                print(f'{id} = Exception 2')
            

        except:
            print(f'Exception 1')
        print('end')
    
    return f'Done with {idList}'
```

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    df = [[1,6] , [2,7] , [3,8] , [4,9] , [5,10]]
    results = executor.map(pathCrawler, df)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks,

Comment: The code you show there does `driver.get` OUTSIDE of the for loop.  Is that really what you have?  If so, then `id` is a built-in function, not an ID number.  In any case, I'm sure you want the `driver.get` inside the loop.

Comment: Thank you! That's a typo on my end of editing it for stack overflow. I will fix that.
The code I am using has driver.get inside the loop. I have two print statements at the start and end of the for loop. For web pages 1,2,3,4,5. They will print 'start' and 'end' but pages 6,7,8,9,10 will only print 'start'.

Comment: Figured out the issue, I had a check at the beginning that was blocking flow.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue, I had a check at the beginning that was blocking flow.